# UINavigationBar custom background image applied in one view controller and then affecting every single view controller in the app

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationbar, uiappearance

I am working with themes in my app. Each theme comes with a custom navigation bar. As a default, I have applied a custom navigation bar in my AppDelegate:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
UIImage *navBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"purplynav.png"];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

If I go to a specific Table View Controller in my app and in the viewWillAppear, I put:

```
if ([self.selectedTheme isEqualToString:@"Blur"])
{
    UIImage *navBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pastelpinknav.png"];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

The "pastelpinknav" suddenly gets applied to every single navigation bar in my app, even though I'm only setting it in this one Table View Controller.

How do I set it so that the navigation bar only applies to this one view controller when set, but is still set to default in the App Delegate when a theme is not set?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change again the navigationBar image in `viewWillDisappear`

```
UIImage *navBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"purplynav.png"];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Because you are using `[UINavigationBar appearance]` it will commonly changes the `UINavigationBar` appearance.

Comment: This worked like a charm - many thanks @Erik for the extremely prompt reply - really appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks @Erik - although the answer is accepted, I just wanted to ask you a quick question. I'm trying to do the same with the tab bar in viewWillAppear and viewDidDisappear, but the tab bar never changes images.. i'm using     UIImage *tabBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Purplepinktop.png"];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBackgroundImage];
- is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

From your view controller call:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[self class], nil] setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImage
                                                                    forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

**Explenation:**

This will change the foo color of the entire app:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setFooColor:@"blue"]
```

In order to change appearance of specific container (i.e your view controller), you need to implement `UIAppearanceContainer` and then call (`UIViewController` already implements it):

```
[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:(Class<UIAppearanceContainer>), ..., nil]
```